# For command, print numbers up to 5 that are divisible by a number which the user enters

Tags: c++

I ran into a task that says to make a program that told me to print numbers up to 5 that are divisible by the number which user enters  with the "for" command.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main{


    int a;
    
    cout<<"Type in a:  "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    for(int i;i<6;i++){
    
    if((a%1)==0)
        cout<<i<<endl;
    
    else if((a%2)==0)
        cout<<i<<endl;
    
    else if((a%3)==0)
        cout<<i<<endl;
        
    
    else if((a%4)==0)
        cout<<i<<endl;
        
    else if((a%5))
        cout<<i<<endl;
    
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: The wording in the question is hard to understand. Can you cut and paste the actual problem description into the question?

Comment: Note: Most problems can be solved on the computer the same way you would solve them with a pencil , paper, and someone shouting numbers at you. The approach may not be optimal, but it gets you started and you can analyze the resulting program and its outputs looking for ways to optimize it once you've finished it. Consider it a rough draft.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you so much, you really saved me. I know the question is kinda weird but your example works.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to initialize `i` in

```
for(int i;i<6;i++){
```

Like:

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
```

Second, you don't really need to test

```
if((a%1)==0)
```

It will always be `0`

Comment: Third: according to the question the divisibility should be tested the other way round: `if (a != 0) for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i){ if (i % a == 0) std::cout << i << '\n'; }`

Comment: I figured it out, thank you so much, you really saved me. I know the question is kinda weird but your example works.